# strange behaviour of linq usage

Tags: linq, ienumerable

I have two tables (t1 and t2) and I select two fields from this tables (f1 and f2).

The list Queries contains the selected data. In this case there are 2 entry with 2 rows.

This is the code:

```
Dim FieldIndexes As New List(Of Integer)
Dim Queries As New List(Of IEnumerable(Of Object()))
For i = 0 To _SqlSyntaxChecker.QueriedTables.Count - 1
    FieldIndexes.Clear()
    For j = 0 To _SqlSyntaxChecker.DataFields.Count - 1
        If _SqlSyntaxChecker.QueriedTables(i).TableName = _SqlSyntaxChecker.DataFields(j).TableName Then FieldIndexes.Add(_SqlSyntaxChecker.DataFields(j).FieldIndexInDataTable)
    Next
    Dim query = _SqlSyntaxChecker.QueriedTables(i).Rows.Select(Function(Row) FieldIndexes.Select(Function(FieldIndex) Row.Item(FieldIndex)).ToArray)
    Queries.Add(query)
    For Each item In Queries(i)
        _OutputDataTable.Rows.Add(item)
    Next
Next
```

And this is the result:

[image]

As you see, everything is ok, I expected this result (it is now not important, that I have on the image 4 rows in one column).

Originally, I wanted to populate the _OutputDataTable outside the for cykle, like so:

```
Dim FieldIndexes As New List(Of Integer)
Dim Queries As New List(Of IEnumerable(Of Object()))
For i = 0 To _SqlSyntaxChecker.QueriedTables.Count - 1
    FieldIndexes.Clear()
    For j = 0 To _SqlSyntaxChecker.DataFields.Count - 1
        If _SqlSyntaxChecker.QueriedTables(i).TableName = _SqlSyntaxChecker.DataFields(j).TableName Then FieldIndexes.Add(_SqlSyntaxChecker.DataFields(j).FieldIndexInDataTable)
    Next
    Dim query = _SqlSyntaxChecker.QueriedTables(i).Rows.Select(Function(Row) FieldIndexes.Select(Function(FieldIndex) Row.Item(FieldIndex)).ToArray)
    Queries.Add(query)
Next

For Each q In Queries
    For Each item In q
        _OutputDataTable.Rows.Add(item)
    Next
Next
```

But as you see, the result is wrong:

[image]

The result should be the same.

What can cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is linked to `i` field (using closures). But queries are execute after first cycle, so `i` already have its last value when query is executed.

You can check "Access to modified closure" topic over internet (mainly it's about delegates but actually same thing works for expression trees).

Comment: I searched the problem "access to modified closure" and edited the code (declaced local variables in the for cycle). It works now as excepted.